Laravel Ui No load after reload the page
On reloading the page in Laravel, UI is not visible, only HTML is visible in the page and the link also calls the file path.
This problem occurs only in form page.
I am working on a project in the host
enter image description here
this is my code
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- start page title -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="page-title-box d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="mb-sm-0 font-size-18">Form Repeater</h4>

                <div class="page-title-right">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Forms</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Form Repeater</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end page title -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Example</h4>
                    <form class="repeater" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div data-repeater-list="group-a">
                            <div data-repeater-item="" class="row">
                                <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" name="group-a[0][untyped-input]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email ID">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Subject">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="resume">Resume</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="resume">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3 col-lg-2">
                                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                                    <textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-lg-2 align-self-center">
                                    <div class="d-grid">
                                        <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <input data-repeater-create="" type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-3 mt-lg-0" value="Add">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Nested</h4>
                    <form class="outer-repeater">
                        <div data-repeater-list="outer-group" class="outer">
                            <div data-repeater-item="" class="outer">
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="formname">Name :</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formname" placeholder="Enter your Name...">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="formemail">Email :</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="formemail" placeholder="Enter your Email...">
                                </div>

                                <div class="inner-repeater mb-4">
                                    <div data-repeater-list="inner-group" class="inner mb-3">
                                        <label>Phone no :</label>
                                        <div data-repeater-item="" class="inner mb-3 row">
                                            <div class="col-md-10 col-8">
                                                <input type="text" class="inner form-control" placeholder="Enter your phone no...">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2 col-4">
                                                <div class="d-grid">
                                                    <input data-repeater-delete="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary inner" value="Delete">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input data-repeater-create="" type="button" class="btn btn-success inner" value="Add Number">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label class="d-block mb-3">Gender :</label>

                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="outer-group[0][inlineRadioOptions]" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Male</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="outer-group[0][inlineRadioOptions]" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Female</label>
                                    </div>                                                          
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="formmessage">Message :</label>
                                    <textarea id="formmessage" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Your Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->

</div>
@endsection

I want that after reloading the page my page should appear with the same UI design as seen in other pages. There is same problem in all form pages. UI appears only after clearing the cache.
Laravel Framework 11.33.2

which method you used to append html in dom, append, html or something else?

Are you rendering html on the server side?

yes
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/34112700
i am facing this problem
I am not able to understand anything
I am working on localhost
Can you tell me the solution

@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')


@endsection
Are you using render() method while rendering on the server side?

i'm not using any render() method
this is basic form only add product brand

If you have any HTML you rendered from the server side and return a response as JSON, then you need to use the render() method. Otherwise, it will be treated as a string in DOM if you append it through js.

For example: view('view_name', data_array[])->render();
